# How to figure out the pros and cons of a review paper?

Tags: graduate-school

My professor has asked me to do a literature review of a review paper. This is my first time doing a review. What method should I follow? any tips for beginners?

Comment: This is very field specific and is something you should probably discuss in more detail with your professor.

Comment: Kind of weird to say "do a literature review of a review paper". "Do a literature review of a field" makes more sense. Best to ask your professor what they had in mind.

Comment: Find your professor's publications in or adjacent to the area. If they're cited, that's a pro. If they're not, it's a con. I'm only half joking about that...

Comment: Literature review FOR a review paper?
What field are you in?

Answer (score 0):

Just set up a spreadsheet, make a list of the literature cited in the review paper, categorize it as book/paper/conference proceedings, get the main message of cited papers, do a short statistics of each paper citation and self-citations.

Basically do *something*, write a short discussion to this *something*, write an introduction to this *something + discussion of something*, and put everything in a slideshow that lasts 15 minutes max and show it to your professor.